# Custom UIImage as UIBarButtonItem showing up pixelated/blurry

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uibarbuttonitem

I'm using a custom image as a bar button item. Looks good on iPhone screens, but seems to be pixelated when running on a larger display (iPads).

iPad2:

[image: iPad2 simulator]

iPhone 6S:

[image: iPhone 6S simulator]

Here's my code:

```
// Set Custom Image for Bar Button Item
    let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "Share.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action:"shareButtonClicked", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDragInside)
    button.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```

How should I set the image scale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPhone 6s has a retina display. The iPad 2 does not. Try it on any version of iPad later than that one, and it will be a retina display, and I bet it won't show as pixelated.

It's possible you may be able to improve the image used on the non-retina display by [choosing the resampling method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling) from a larger image carefully.

Comment: I was hoping it was a scaling problem I could control, but looks like you're right as it appears okay on iPad Retina. Other UIButtons don't appear anywhere near as pixelated, but perhaps that's related to using a custom image for this one? Thanks for the insight though!

Comment: Well, you're specifying the frame in points, so I assume it's scaling appropriately to fill that frame (depending on your fill method). Please accept my answer if that resolved the issue for you.

You could possible create an antialiased version of the button image for the iPad2. The easiest way to do that is to take your retina image and resample it to the smaller size. That way the diagonal lines would have some mid-tones along the edges.

Comment: Appreciate the help!